# How do I Filter an XML via an XSLT with xml params

Tags: xslt

Here is my input XML:

```
<Books>
  <Book>
    <BookId>1</BookId>
    <Des>Dumm1</Des>
    <Comments/>
    <OrderDateTime>04/06/2009 12:37</OrderDateTime>
  </Book>
  <Book>
    <BookId>2</BookId>
    <Des>Dummy2</Des>
    <Comments/>
    <OrderDateTime>04/07/2009 12:37</OrderDateTime>
  </Book>
  <Book>
    <BookId>3</BookId>
    <Des>Dumm12</Des>
    <Comments/>
    <OrderDateTime>05/06/2009 12:37</OrderDateTime>
  </Book>
  <Book>
    <BookId>4</BookId>
    <Des>Dummy2</Des>
    <Comments/>
    <OrderDateTime>06/07/2009 12:37</OrderDateTime>
  </Book>
</Books>
```

I pass an XML param and my Input XML is

```
<BookIDs>
  <BookID>2</BookID>
  <BookID>3</BookID>
</BookIDs>
```

My output should be like

```
<Books>
  <Book>
    <BookId>2</BookId>
    <Des>Dummy2</Des>
    <Comments/>
    <OrderDateTime>04/07/2009 12:37</OrderDateTime>
  </Book>
  <Book>
    <BookId>3</BookId>
    <Des>Dumm12</Des>
    <Comments/>
    <OrderDateTime>05/06/2009 12:37</OrderDateTime>
  </Book>
</Books>
```

How do I accomplish this using XSLT?

Comment: Can you post your attempt first, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in Saxon 6.5.5...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.1">
    <xsl:param name="nodeset">
        <BookIDs><BookID>2</BookID><BookID>3</BookID></BookIDs>
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="/Books">
        <Books>
            <xsl:variable name="Copy">
                <wrap>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Book"/>
                </wrap>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:for-each select="$nodeset/BookIDs/BookID">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$Copy/wrap/Book[BookId=current()]"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Books>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A pure XSLT solution will be pretty brittle though. Sub-query predicates didn't work, neither did a key. It is dependent upon the param being recognized as a node-set--which I was unable to achieve with a dynamic value (as opposed to the default in my example), even with [exsl:node-set](http://www.exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/index.html). This is also wasteful in that it copies all the Book elements from the source document.

There may be a better solution in XSLT 2.0. Alternately, if you are initiating your transform with some other language/tool, there may be better approaches available there. Another possibility could include the use of [exsl:document](http://www.exslt.org/exsl/elements/document/) to load your source document or params.